# Make CNAME point to Domain/controller

Tags: dns, subdomain, azure-appservice, godaddy-api

I have an Azure app with the address: `JohnDoeApps.azurewebsites.net`, and I have a page/controller on there under the address `JohnDoeApps.azurewebsites.net/clockapp`

I also have a GoDaddy domain called: ClockApp.com.au and I want this domain to point to `JohnDoeApps.azurewebsites.net/clockapp`.

Unfortunately the DNS settings are only allowing me to point to `JohnDoeApps.azurewebsites.net` and not `JohnDoeApps.azurewebsites.net/clockapp`.

I am currently using redirection to get around this. But how to I set it up to point and go to `JohnDoeApps.azurewebsites.net/clockapp`?

Comment: Just spoke to GoDaddy, they say there is no way to go to a specific page.

Comment: But surely there must be a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up CNAME to point to a controller page like this `domain.com/controller` is impossible. Redirection is the only way, as stated by my domain provider.